# Is there a shortcut key to go back to search bar in Chrome in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut key to go back to the search bar on Mac OS X using Chrome while in image search mode?

For example:

1. Enter a search term in Google
2. Go to images search
3. How do you get back to the search bar with the keyboard only?

The only way I’ve found to be able to do this is using the “Find” option.

1. Basically <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to enter “Find” and enter a portion of the search term until it highlights.
2. Then press <kbd>esc</kbd> to exit out of  “Find” mode

Is there an easier way?

Comment: That's usually called a "search form", not a "search bar".  As you can see from some answers/comments below, the search bar means something else (usually the same as the URL bar these days).  Anyway, you can press Shift-Tab multiple times to get there, but that's not very convenient.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will take you back to the url bar in Chrome, which is also a search bar.

Comment: First, `Ctrl-L` doesn't work on Mac OS X, and second, this does not get you to the image search bar.

Comment: Ctrl + l is not equal to cmd + l. I also clearly state it takes you to the url bar search bar.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to go to the URL bar (Omnibox). They want to go here: http://i.imgur.com/VLaSDaC.png. `Cmd-L` brings you to the Omnibox.

Comment: @slhck, the Op' is using `Cmd-F` to bring up the Find box to find his/her search term in the search form.  The end goal is not how to bring up the Find box, but how to get back to to the input box in the search form.

Comment: @jimtut Yes, I know. I've never claimed otherwise. I never talked about how to bring up the `Find` menu. The screenshot I posted in the above comment highlights what the OP wants to focus. `Cmd-L` does not achieve that, hence my initial comment.

Comment: @slhck, you're right, I thought I saw the Find dialog in your pic.  Confused your post with what I saw while trying to reproduce the problem!